# I'm having issues with appendto

Tags: jquery

I'm learning all this stuff and am tripping over every little hurdle. right now I can get append to work but my instructions say to use appendto. I know its a simple inverse but it's not being nice to me.

the code that I have is:

```
list.append('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>');
```

but needs to be changed to appendto. Would any of you show me how that should be written.

Comment: `$('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>').appendTo(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>')` will return the object `list`.

`$('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>').appendTo(list)` will return the object of appended `li`

You are trying to use .appendTo() which was the second one.

### [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: All were helpful but yours were most descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>').appendTo(list);
```

Comment: the instruction I have say to minimize factory calls so I was trying to do it without the $(). but maybe that is why I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>').appendTo(list);
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) is the API documentation for `.appendTo()`.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the API docs. I think my problem was I was trying to avoid using the $(). project guideline talks about reducing there use but doesn't really give any details. Thanks for your help though, It will do until I get a hold of the instructor.